# Generalized Method of Moments in R:How to set starting value?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run GMM estimation in R, with `gmm` package.
I find that estimates are very sensitive to option `t0`, which is starting value.

However, as far as I know, there is no starting value in **STATA** or **SAS** to estimates GMM. If the estimates are sensitive to starting value, How should I set `t0` to get the same results from commercial programs?

*Codes and data included*

To be clear, I include my codes and data. I'm trying to estimate `lambda`. My question is, the estimate of lambda varies too much across starting value (you may set starting value of lambda as 0 and then compare the result). Hence, I'm not sure which estimate should I rely on.

[instrument.csv](https://sites.google.com/site/yongseokkim91/data/instrument.csv?attredirects=0&d=1)

[test_assets.csv](https://sites.google.com/site/yongseokkim91/data/test_assets.csv?attredirects=0&d=1)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gmm)

instrument <- read_csv("instrument.csv")
test_assets <- read_csv("test_assets.csv")

# Define Moment Conditions
g <- function(params, y){

 # Number of instrument variables: 6
 l <- dim(instrument)[2]

 # Moment condition 1: 6 x 1
 u_jt <- y - instrument %*% params[1:l]
 mom_cond1 <- c(u_jt) * instrument

 # Moment condition 2: 6 x 1
 u_mt <- test_assets$vwretd - instrument %*% params[(l+1):(l+l)]
 mom_cond2 <- c(u_mt) * instrument

 # Moment condition 3: 6 x 1
 e_jt <- y - params[l+l+1] * u_jt * u_mt
 mom_cond3 <- c(e_jt) * instrument

 # Moment condition: 18 x 1
 mom_cond <- list(mom_cond1, mom_cond2, mom_cond3) %>%
  reduce(cbind)

 return(mom_cond)
}

# Define starting values.
t0 <- c(gamma1 = -0.01, gamma2 = 0.1, gamma3 = 0.05,
        gamma4 = 5, gamma5 = 20, gamma6 = 5,
        gamma7 = -0.01, gamma8 = 0.01, gamma9 = 0.01,
        gamma10 = 8, gamma11 = 13, gamma12 = 3,
        lambda = 10
        )

y <- test_assets$decret1

gmm_results <- gmm(g, y, t0)
summary(gmm_results)
```

Comment: No data, No code, No answer. (Close as unclear)

Comment: I think the question is clear, however, it should be updated to include some data and the code. This will make the question very high standard.

Comment: For general, starting values are very important. Good starting values return good estimate. You could try to use one common method to get a starting values for your model. Or you could try to use several starting values and the one that give you a good estimate ( based on selection criteria) should be used as the good one for your model. Please provide much more information to help us to help you.

Comment: @42 I edited my post. sorry.

Comment: @F.AMER Thanks for your answer. I edited my post.

Comment: As I said, try different starting values. Then, use AIC, BIC to select the best model. The best model is selected based on small values of AIC and BIC.